# Is the language for the following grammar is correct? $L= \{a^i b^j c^k d^l : i,j,k,l \geqslant0 \text{ and }i+k=j+l\}$

Tags: context-free-grammar

I tried to solve it like this:

---

\begin{align}
A &\to aAd+S+\epsilon \\
S &\to PQR \\
P &\to aPb+\epsilon \\
Q &\to bQc+\epsilon \\
R &\to cRd+\epsilon
\end{align}

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please include your question in the body of the question, instead of putting it only in the title.

Comment: Please use mathjax.